# How to prevent a WKInterfaceController from scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a `WKInterfaceController`, whose I don't want it to be scrollable, but it seems decided to scroll even when my master group's height and width are set to **1** in **Relative to container**.

I were thinking that It isn't possible until I see Fitstar and Skype apps.

Answer (score 8):

There is a way - inside Storyboard:

Set the tag: "Fixed to screen edges"

After that, scrolling is disabled for the WKInterfaceController.

[image]

Comment: So I have a button and table in my interface controller, when I scroll through the table it will hide the button and vice-versa, is there a way I can fix the position of other objects other than the table?

Comment: First of: I have only played with WatchOS1-3 so far, and therefore I am not quite certain if the newest WatchOS offers your desired feature.
You would like to fix-in-position parts of your watch-screen and other parts should scroll. Here is what I know:

Comment: As far as I know, for a WKInterfaceController you only have an attribute called "Fixed to screen edges". But this seems to fix everyting.
Unfortunately, on the watch you don't have a Z hierarchy. So therefore you cannot make view-layers like on the iPhone.

Comment: All this said, I read that as of watchOS4, it's possible to create groups with overlapping content. (i.e. set a group's Layout attribute in the Attribute inspector to "Overlap").
But I have never tried if one group can be fixed in position and another "overlapping" can scroll...

Maybe somebody else knows about newest WatchOS features to this respect. I am sorry I don't have a ready-made solution for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and helpful reply. I really appreciate it. I knew about that overlapping layout and tried that too but didn't help. Anyways, I will also write it back here if I will make it working.

Answer (score 2):

Looking and testing around found a solution:

Make sure that in Interface Controller's Attribute Inspector you have the insets set to **default**

**UPDATE:**

You need to fit your view, in the **<=100%** of the view, there's no other workaround, if you have more than that, the `WKInterfaceController` will scroll automatically.

Comment: Did you solve this? I checked Interface Controller's insets to default but still scrolling? If you found the correct answer please share